# CSS selector has same property with multiple value, can it cause performance issues?

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

I was bit curious about a question that come to mind, even though it is not standard/good practice to write coed in such a way.

What if a CSS selector has same property with multiple value for example

```
.selector {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding:10px 5px 10px 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

as you can se **padding** and **margin** both properties has been added multiple times

Can it create performance issues for a html page if we have multiple selectors like this in a big application ?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions and observations you provide here.

Comment: I don't see how / why it causes performance problem. The example doesn't make sense though, unless you place the shorthand properties first and specific properties (*-top) later.

Comment: This really isn't opinion based. There's a lot of concrete evidence about how little effect this can have on performance.

Comment: Negligible performance impact unless you're doing something ludicrous